# rtabmap: t265 fisheye images instead of zed stereo images

Tags: slam, navigation, ros-kinetic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to test rtabmap with t265 fisheye images as input.

I suppose I cant just put topics from t265 camera instead of zed topics in rtabmap.launch because zed camera's physical parameters differs from t265. Or can I?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/343137/rtabmap:-t265-fisheye-images-instead-of-zed-stereo-images/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2020-02-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it is possible, but with an extra step to do stereo fisheye calibration. See this post for details: http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Slam-using-Intel-RealSense-tracking-camera-T265-tp6333p6343.html

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on 2020-02-11**:
I tried! https://yadi.sk/i/mxX-B_XGjkOkJg
what do you think?

there I am using t265 visual odometry provided by Intel, dont think it would be better using rtabmap's visual odometry?

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2020-02-20**:
I didn't do exhaustive tests, but it seems that T265 odometry is quite good... in good conditions, while being computed onboard of the camera. You can look at this post: http://official-rtab-map-forum.206.s1.nabble.com/Comparison-between-realsense-D435-vs-T265-vs-T265-D435-dual-setup-td6456.html, in particular this video (using rtabmap odometry with T265) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tm8nttMR7SQ and this one (using t265 odometry) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwmNHHoDvvI.